# PyInstaller error with email module

Tags: python, email, pyinstaller

First create a script named `test.py`, with one line in it:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
```

Save it and run `makespec.py` and `build.py`, then I get the `test.exe`. This is what I get while running `test.exe`:

```
F:\SW\trunk\test\dist>test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test\build\pyi.win32\test\outPYZ1.pyz/email", line 79, in __getattr__
  File "F:\SW\trunk\iu.py", line 455, in importHook
    raise ImportError, "No module named %s" % fqname
ImportError: No module named email.mime.multipart
```

Looks like PyInstaller doesn't work well with the email module. I've tried PyInstaller 1.4, 1.5rc, and the latest trunk, none of them worked. Windows Server 2003 /w Python 2.6 here. Any way to get around with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should use `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart`.

It has been [answered](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyinstaller@googlegroups.com/msg01828.html) in the mailgroups ages ago, and it was the first hit when I google "pyinstaller, email". It's such a shame I didn't check it more carefully.